# Convert csv date-time field into Database datetime object

Tags: database, csv, datetime-format

I have a .csv file which has 2 fields `date` and `time` in `DD/MM/YYYY` and `HH:MM:SS` format respectively and I have a field in my database table column name as `updated_on` in `datetime.datetime` format. I am able to parse it into `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` format.

So, My question is how can I convert the .csv fields into the `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`.

PS: Mind that there are 2 separate field for date and time in .csv file. So, how can I combine them and make them as one datetime object, so that I can compare the `updated_on` field value with the combined value of 2 fields of .csv file.

Comment: you need to import data from CSV to database?

Comment: ok, lets do first things first and then we'll move onto the next step. I have 2 fields in csv file `date` and `time` . I concatenated them into one string like `16/08/2013 09:51:43` . So Now I want it to convert this string into python time. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

```
d, m, y = date.split('/')
datetime = "%s-%s-%s " % (y, m, d) + time
```